# Docker stack deploy error about top-level object mappings

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Following along with the Docker getting started guide, https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part3/#your-first-docker-composeyml-file, I'm running into an issue. I've created the docker-compose.yml file and verified that the contents are correct:

```
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    image: joshuabelden/get-started:part2
    deploy:
      replicas: 5
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "0.1"
          memory: 50M
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    networks:
      - webnet
networks:
  webnet:
```

I also verified that I can run my image outside of a swarm. After running the command:

```
 docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml getstartedlab
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Top-level object must be a mapping
```

I can't seem to find any information on the error message.

Comment: Your command worked fine here. Are you using a recent Docker version? (here is 17.07.0-ce)

Comment: This is probably an environment issue. I am at 17.06.1-ce so perhaps an update will resolve this.

Comment: I'm also following the tutorial, I created the docker-compose.yml file in different directory than my Dockerfile and app file, because tutorial says save the file wherever you want. But I get the above error. So I moved the file to the rest of docker files and it worked.

Answer (score 48):

What I did to solve this is I removed the double quotes and made them single quotes to change 
version: "3" -> version: '3'
This removed the error for me, also do this for all double quotes.

Comment: It was probably double quotes were converted to something else. Otherwise, double quotes work as well.

Comment: I don't understand why, but your answer worked for me too. Thank you!!! +1

Comment: Works on WSL2 Ubuntu 20.04 LTS - win11

Comment: This worked for me (Docker 3.8)

Answer (score 20):

You probably didn't save after modifying the docker-compose.yml file. So if you run 'docker compose up' without having saved, you get the error about top-level object mappings.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Confirmed layer 8 issue...

Answer (score 5):

You have to add the "volumes" where your code should be copied:

```
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    image: iconkam/get-started:part2
    deploy:
      replicas: 5
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "0.1"
          memory: 50M
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    networks:
      - webnet
networks:
  webnet:
```

Comment: That didn't change anything for me. I still get the same error.

Answer (score 5):

I am using Symfony 6 on Linux Ubuntu and I had the same type of problem but not with "docker stack".
I had this problem simply when running:
docker-compose up

```
$ docker-compose up
Top-level object must be a mapping
```

I searched for a long time to find a solution.
No solution described here worked.

In fact the problem was caused by the presence of a default file in Symfony 6:

```
docker-compose.override.yml
```

I commented all the content inside but it was not enough.

Renaming the file made the command "docker-compose up" worked.
Deleting the file is also a solution ;-)

Answer (score 4):

This error arises from the formatting of the file. Please try to convert the file encoding to UTF-8 and you will be able to run `docker stack deploy` command. Double quotes is not an issue here.

Answer (score 2):

This happens when Docker is running in Kubernetes mode and not swarm.

I fixed it by changing it to Swarm through settings > Kubernetes[image]

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it's just the formatting in the file. I recommend selecting your text in the compose file and seeing if you have a trailing blank space somewhere.

In my case, I had a space right after the image tag.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I wrapped all the values in double quotes expect the **replica**, and it got fixed. Like so:

```
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    # replace username/repo:tag with your name and image details
    image: "image details"
    deploy:
      replicas: 5
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "0.1"
          memory: "50M"
      restart_policy:
        condition: "on-failure"
    ports:
      - "4000:80"
    networks:
      - "webnet"
networks:
  webnet:
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably you forgot to save the docker compose file.

Answer (score 1):

I just had this problem and the reason was that I had an empty `docker-compose.override.yml`

Comment: adding `version` like `version: '3'` solves that

Answer (score 0):

Just close and reopen Terminal again - and run command again.

p.s. I'm using Windows + WSL Terminal. Time to time randomly see same error.

Comment: Why would this work?

Comment: @ndemarco Have no idea, why it worked for me. :D As I got this error randomly, without doing changes in the actual docker compose file.
I agree that this solution sounds silly, but as we know the humans makes silly mistakes also in the software code.

Answer (score 0):

Another reason this may be happening while you're pulling your hair out:

You have the environment variable `COMPOSE_FILE` set, which refers to a file which is empty or an invalid yml file.

In my case it was set to `docker-compose.combined.yml` while running `docker compose config > docker-compose.combined.yml`, which first created an empty file to write to, and then stated the error `Top-level object must be a mapping` while trying to read that empty file.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error in vs code when the autosaving crashed for some reason when trying to save the docker-compose.yml file
In order to resolve it you need to delete the file and recreated it again (copy the contains before deletion xd)

I hope this helps

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Seems this is because of yml file having formatting issues.
I just copied everything from this file and pasted into a newly created file using notepad++/notepad and saved.
Later, I used that file to run docker-compose command.
It worked smoothly.

Comment: Ok, but this does not answer to the question. Can you explain what Notepad++ changed?

Comment: There was an encoding issue in the original text. There was one character which was not supported . Moving to notepad++ fixed that.

Answer (score 0):

I have used PyCharm and it generates a command to run: `docker-compose -f Dockerfile up`.
The problem is that for some reason this error occurs with the `-f` flag, but without it everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing is that Docker does not recognize the file because it is not saved. Try saving the file and get rid of the quotations and putting them as single apostrophes and that should do the trick.

Saving the file is what solved the error for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Late reply but perhaps it will help an unsuspecting someone in the future.

This same error will will occur when using docker compose with more than one file string argument while in the incorrect directory.